# Removing characters during a gridview update

Tags: asp.net, t-sql, gridview, sql-server-2012

**UPDATE - Please note that I'm attampting to get this challenge solved with a SQL 2012 solution.**

I'm in the process of trying to work out a SQL puzzle that I'm sure has a simple solution but I'm spinning my wheels on it at the moment.  I'm trying to work with a field in a gridview that I need to take a long file name that I'm entering for the first time and chop all but the six characters on the left side of the file name during the update process.  The rest of the fields in the gridview have already been entered so this isn't an INSERT scenario but an UPDATE operation.  I've figured out the basic command for that (LEFT) but what I need to do is to have the code behind the page (I'm assuming with SQL code) take a filename in this format:

Here's the code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
<Columns>
<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="line" HeaderText="Line" SortExpression="line" InsertVisible="False" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="data" HeaderText="Data" SortExpression="data" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="new_data" HeaderText="New Data" SortExpression="new_data" />
<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The output code looks something like this...

Line                       Data                                                                  New Data
.............................................................................................................................
 1        131024_000000-A_blah_de_blah_1of12.pdf               131024
 2        131024_000000-A_blah_de_blah_1of12.rtf
 3        131024_000000-A_blah_de_blah_2of12.pdf
 4        131024_000000-A_blah_de_blah_2of12.rtf
 5        131025_000000-A_blah_de_blah_3of12.pdf

and so on....

What I'm attempting to do with this is to find a way via SQL to take the file name behind the scenes in the data column, cut off the file name to the right of the first six digits and then write it to the 'new_data' column.

Here's what I've tried:

```
UPDATE  [dbo].[left_test] 
SET [new_data] = 
(SELECT LEFT(Data,6) 
FROM [dbo].[left_test])
WHERE [data] = @data;
GO
```

Which yields the following error:

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.
```

INSERT INTO dbo.left_test new_data (data)
SELECT LEFT(data,6) from dbo.left_test

Since I haven't worked with this scenario before I don't have the foggiest idea how to incorpoate an update statement in this gridview and leverage the left command (if that's what's required here).  Do I create a stored procedure and call it when the gridview is updated or do I add the code to the ASP page in the middle of the SQL UPDATE code?

If more information is required here, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part returns multiple records to update in one record, which is failing:

```
(SELECT LEFT(Data,6) 
FROM [dbo].[left_test])
```

You should change the SQL to:

```
UPDATE  [dbo].[left_test] 
SET [new_data] =  LEFT(Data,6) 
WHERE [data] = @data;
GO
```

**Explanation:**

1. This subquery 
   `SELECT LEFT(Data,6) FROM [dbo].[left_test])`
   returns multiple records, first 6 characters from all records. But you need only the one which has same id. You can fix it this way:

   SELECT LEFT(Data,6)
   FROM [dbo].[left_test]
   WHERE [data] = @data
2. Since you are updating same row, the subquery :

   `SELECT LEFT(Data,6) 
   FROM [dbo].[left_test]
   WHERE [data] = @data`

   is same as

   `LEFT(Date, 6)`

Comment: Just so that I can learn this for future reference can you explain what I need to keep in mind (theory wise) when in a similar scenario again?

Comment: I run the query in ssms...I would say this is a common issue and easy to figure out in ssms.

Comment: That did the trick!  I'll award you the bounty when the site allows me to (about 6 hours from now).

Comment: I am glad that it helped! Added some explanations as well.

Answer (score 1):

For the `UPDATE` command just send a string of six characters to the logic that builds the SQL statement in your code using the `.Substring()` method, like this:

```
var longFilename = "131114_blahblahblahblahblah_moreblahblahblahblah.doc";
var sixCharName = longFilename.Substring(0, 6);
```

Now send the `sixCharName` to the logic that builds the `UPDATE` SQL statement.

Comment: The challenge here is that I can't hardcode the file names.  It's going to be a random name for each file.  I could have sworn there was some way to put this into the UPDATE command associated with the Gridview code.  Is this not correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to use the _ as a delimiter to find the first part of the name. Then use the query as a subquery and update the table.

Here is an example:

```
UPDATE TableToUpdate
SET ColumnInTable = SubQueryWithData.FileName
From
(SELECT  SUBSTRING(data.columndata, 0 ,CHARINDEX('_', data.ColumnData) ) AS FileName
FROM    ( SELECT   1 AS RecordID, '123456_789' AS ColumnData
        ) AS Data) AS SubQueryWithData
        WHERE TableToUpdate.ID = SubQueryWithData.ID
```